# Get columns values from dataGridView and append them to the hosts file?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm trying to modify the hosts file ( so i add the lines to it ) , host file which is on c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\

I've added a dataGridView with two columns in my form ( URL and RedirectTo ), now it looks something like this :

[image]

what i want to do is to read the current value of dataGrid and append them to a the hosts file, so the text file will look like this :

![enter image description here][2]

How to access the columns values and read them in order to append them to the hosts file ( End of file ) in the following format :

```
www.algerie-actualites.com       www.monde-presse.com
algerie-actudz.com/              www.monde-presse.com
```

(I'm not using any DataSet / Database to read data from, the user may type these web addresses in the DataGridView!!)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: i'm trying to modify the hosts file ( so i add these lines to it ) , host file which is on c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\

Comment: I'am asking what code you tried and it didn't worked? If none, so this is not the place to ask to write code for you or google an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
var lines = grid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(r => String.Join("\t", r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
            .Select(c => c.Value)) + Environment.NewLine);
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(path, lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\sample.txt", FileMode.Open);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

for (int i = 0; i < gvEmp.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int colCount = gvEmp.Rows[i].Cells.Count;
    for (int j=0; j < colCount; j++)
    {
       sw.Write(gvEmp.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text + " , ");
    }
    sw.WriteLine();
}
sw.Flush();
fs.Close();
```